# Getting autocode, receipt number back from the Square API

Tags: square-connect

I'm developing an app that uses Square credit card processing API. In the Square web panel, after a charge I see things like "authcode" and receipt number in that interface, but I can't find where the API gives me back this data.

Also, when charging with the Square virtual terminal, I can pace a comment with the charge. When the API makes a charge that comment is set to "online transaction."

So can I have the software leave a comment with the API, and can I get the auto code and receipt numbers through the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all of the features available in Square Dashboard are available via the API at this time, though we are actively working on expanding the API capabilities, particularly around itemizations and receipts.

You can add external `reference_id` and `note` to a transaction if you want to associate some external metadata. Receipts can be retrieved with the older retrieve and list payments endpoints. See here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/?q=receipt#datatype-payment

Comment: Okay thanks for the quick reply. Mostly what I am trying to achieve is to allow a CSR to easily look at the Square Dashboard and locate a customer's charge. Where on the dashboard would a reference_id and/or a note be displayed?

Comment: Those fields are only available via API at this time. You won't see them in Dashboard.

Comment: Okay, is there anything at all I can set in the API, or get from the API, that will show up easily on the dashboard?

Comment: You could get creative with customers, and other types, but until we release e-commerce itemizations it will be hard to do so with transactions.